# How do I allow for multiple statements in my reducer?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-actions

I am forced to use the [redux-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-actions). In my reducer this code works:

```
return handleActions({
  [FOOBAR]: (state) => ({
    ...state, value: 'the user clicked something 2'
  })
}, {})
```

However, in the reducer I would like to `console.log` some stuff. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code currently returns an object from an arrow function to indicate the subsequent state. Instead of using shorthand arrow function syntax to implicitly return the object, you can use [a block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) to house multiple statements including your `console.log`, not just an implicit return:

```
[FOOBAR]: (state) => {
  console.log('Inside FOOBAR action')
  return {
    ...state, value: 'the user clicked something 2'
  }
}
```

The `{}` symbolize a block instead of an object literal because of the missing `()`<sup>1</sup>. Thus, you can use other statements inside the block, but you must return your subsequent state object because it does not implicitly return.

---

The reason why `{}` is a block and not an object literal here is because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have multiple acceptable syntaxes, one using a block:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
```

The JavaScript engine interprets the `{}` as a block. So, your code has `({})` which does mean an object literal because the parentheses can only *be wrapped around an expression*. Since a block is not an expression, and the object literal *is an expression*, the engine interprets it as an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your arrow function above in the more verbose style that will allow you to include multiple statements. Then you can slip in a console log.

```
return handleActions({
  [FOOBAR]: (state) => {
    console.log('I LOG ALL THE THINGS');
    return {...state, value: 'the user clicked something 2'};
  }
}, {});
```